# How to show that a Catch block for the Parent-exception will handle subclasses as well

Tags: java, oop, exception, inheritance, inner-classes

I have met this problem.

I have created a class `CatHandler`, with `3` inner classes (`ExceptionAlpha` *extends* `Exception`, `ExceptionBeta` *extends* `ExceptionAlpha`, `ExceptionGammer` *extends* `ExceptionBeta`). These three *exception subclasses* are empty; they ***contain no code***. All ***code should be written*** in `CatHandler`.

Now the question is to write some code in `CatHandler` to show that `ExceptionBeta` and `ExceptionGammer` will be caught in the catch block of type `ExceptionAlpha`?

For the output, we can use `System.err.println()`, `getMessage()` and `printStackTrace()` and other appropriate print statements to show that the *exception subclasses* have been successfully caught.

I'm wondered how to show that exception handling happens in such a way? It is really confusing.

```
public class CatHandler {

    class ExceptionAlpha extends Exception {

    }

    class ExceptionBeta extends ExceptionAlpha {

    }


    class ExceptionGammer extends ExceptionBeta {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to prove it. It is guaranteed by the Java Language Specification. You don't need to test or verify the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the question is to write some code in CatHandler to show that ExceptionBeta and ExceptionGammer will be caught in the catch block of type ExceptionAlpha.

First, you need to declare a few methods that will *throw* `ExceptionBeta` and `ExceptionGamma`.

Because both of them are *checked exceptions*, you should include a `throws` *clause* in the method declarations.

It's better to define all the nested classes as `static`, otherwise these exceptions will always require an object enclosing class (i.e. `CatHandler`) in order to be instantiated.

The code in the `main()` invokes the unsafe behavior and handless it with `catch` blocks expecting `ExceptionAlpha` or its subtypes.

To demonstrate the *actual type* of a caught exception, we can extract the *class name* from its `Class` object or print stack trace (*class name* will mentioned at the very beginning a stack trace). Both options are shown below.

```
public class CatHandler {

    public void m1() throws ExceptionBeta {
        throw new ExceptionBeta();
    }

    public void m2() throws ExceptionGamma {
        throw new ExceptionGamma();
    }

    public static class ExceptionAlpha extends Exception{}
    public static class ExceptionBeta extends ExceptionAlpha {}
    public static class ExceptionGamma extends ExceptionBeta {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CatHandler catHandler = new CatHandler();
        try {
            catHandler.m1();
        } catch (ExceptionAlpha e) {
            System.out.println("Class name: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            catHandler.m2();
        } catch (ExceptionAlpha e) {
            System.out.println("Class name: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Class name: ExceptionBeta
Class name: ExceptionGamma

_ path _.CatHandler$ExceptionBeta
    at _ path _.CatHandler.m1(CatHandler.java:6)
    at _ path _.CatHandler.main(CatHandler.java:36)

_ path _.CatHandler$ExceptionGamma
    at _ path _.CatHandler.m2(CatHandler.java:10)
    at _ path _.CatHandler.main(CatHandler.java:42)
```

Comment: @Kevin Ok, then to prove that `catch` block it able to handle subclasses, you can print a stack trace. Amended, take a look now.

Answer (score 0):

Override `getMessage` in each exception to return something different. Polymorphism will allow `ExceptionAlpha` to catch it's subclasses and then use the specific implementations of the respective ones.